# Scrollview in a Scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

This probably will look quit strange but I want to use two nested scrollviews. At some point the outer scrollview needs to stop scrolling and pass all scrolling behaviour to the inner scrollview.

My layout looks something like this.

```
<CustomOuterScrollView>
   <LinearLayout/>
   <CustomInnerScrollView/>
</CustomOuterScrollView>
```

I made two classes where I override the onInterceptTouchEvent. 
For the CustomOuterScrollView this is the following:

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( MotionEvent ev )
{
    if ( stopScrolling )
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent( ev );
    }
}
```

And For the CustomInnerScrollView this look just like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent( MotionEvent ev )
{
    return true;
}
```

Now, the biggest problem I have is the following. After the point where stopScrolling variable is set true the outerscrollview doesn't consume the events anymore but passes them to the CustomInnerScrollView. Which when I debug, actually comes in to the onInterceptTouchEvent. The only problem is that the InnerScrollView will not scroll. Anyone who has an idea? I know this is not normally done, using nested scrollviews. But due to design issues it's not possible to do something else.

Comment: Maybe you should distinguish he currently scrolling view in the `onInterceptTouchEvent` , if it's the Inner one, then reverse the if statement?

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. But, there is no distinguish between the scrolling views needed. The outerview needs to get all scrolling behaviour untill aprox 50% is scrolled and then the innerscrollingview starts to scroll.

Comment: Ok, then put inside the `onInterceptTouchEvent` an `if` clause inside the already existing `if` clause to check for these 50% (I guess you already figured out how to determine this) and if those 50% are reached - `return super.onInterceptTouchEvent( ev );` (for example).

Comment: The stopScrolling variable determines this state.

Comment: Then for the part of `CustomInnerScrollView `can 't you just `return super.onInterceptTouchEvent( ev );` instead of `true`? I think that true just disables the scroll.